# Is there a way to read a specific file from a ZipInputStream without having to iterate over the whole entry set?

Tags: java, zipinputstream

I would like to know if there is a way to read a particular file directly from a `ZipFile` / `ZipInputStream` without having to iterate over the entire entry set. I imagine this could be quite an overhead, if the archive contains a large number of files. Is there a better way?

I know this can be done with `TrueZip` and I've done it a while ago, but I am wondering if the 1.8 SDK contains something more adequate nowadays...?

Comment: AFAIK No. I tend to iterate over it and build List or Map

Comment: No there isn't. The file is somewhere inside the ZIP file, you have to iterate to get to it. It isn't as expensive as you might think, just a series of seeks.

Answer (score 3):

In java 7, you can treat [zip files as a Filesystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).

While this does give some convenient access methods, it is not likely going to perform any different than iterating over the list of entries to find a single file.

To obtain a input stream for a specific path:

```
Path zipfile = Paths.get("/codeSamples/zipfs/zipfstest.zip");
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipfile, null);
Path entry = fs.getPath("/my/entry.txt");
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(entry);
```

Also be sure to [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#close--) the FileSystem instance when you are done with it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-

Comment: Should I understand you can simply wrap the `Path` obtained from the `FileSystem` with a `FileInputStream` and just go ahead and read it? (An example would be great).

Comment: @carlspring I have added a simple example. Note that the oracle doc on the Zip File System Provider that I linked to includes some simple examples and a link to source code with more in depth examples.

Comment: Thanks, for the example, but it doesn't compile, as `FileSystem.newFileSystem` accepts a `String`, not a `Path`. From what I've seen, the path seems to need to be like `uri:file:///path/to/foo.txt`, but I can't seem to get it to work. Have you tried the code above?

Comment: I copied from the Oracle doc. I updated to reflect the available method. Have you actually read the Oracle doc? The second sentence states: `The zip file system provider treats a zip or JAR file as a file system...`

Answer (score 0):

`ZipFile` has the `getEntry(String)` method for doing this. If you mean with the code never iterating through the entries, however, then no, you can not do it. The entries in a zip file are unordered so the best you can get is the O(n) iterative search.

[Javadoc link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry%28java.lang.String%29)